# Store slug and path based on post ID which is created before in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, closures

I have a quite complicated form, which has a lot of fields - everything works fine, but I also need to store a slug and path to thumbnail. The problem is, that when I am using store method and create a post, I need to dynamically create that slug and path based on the post ID (which is not created yet and therefore I don't have an ID).

This is the chunk of the code I use to store the main post data:

```
Post::forceCreate([
            'title' => $title,
            'slug' => create_url_slug($title, $id),
            'thumbnail' => thumbPath($id),
            'description' => request('description'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password')),
            'user_id' => get_user_id()
        ]);
```

Here I passed two functions -> create_url_slug and thumbPath. If I put these functions above this chunk of code, the error will be thrown because the ID does not exist yet. On the other hand, if I put these functions under this code, the error will also appear, because those functions would be undefined. Can I somehow use closures or divide this method to two parts?

Thanks anybody in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to create the model and right after assigning the values for example

```
$post = Post::forceCreate([
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => request('description'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password')),
            'user_id' => get_user_id()
        ]);

$post->slug = create_url_slug($title, $post->id);
$post->thumbnail = thumbPath($post->id);
$post->save();
```

I do not recall if `make` creates an id for the Model else you could use `Post::make` and save a call to the database. Worth a try.

Comment: Glad i could i help :)